# Chart.js How to create dynamic tooltip with clickable buttons inside it

Tags: javascript, charts, tooltip

I want to have a dynamic tooltip inside my chart with buttons inside it.
Look like what i want is to create a custom tooltip. Once created, i try to hover over i but i can't.
At first i thought it was impossible so i decided to create my very own custom tooltip which didn't turn out well. I created my own html component and a function to show this component, the function was fired when i hovered over a dot in the chart. The result was awful, the tooltip was blinking all the time so I headed back to the custom tooltip option chart.js provides. However i haven't found a way to keep the custom tooltip open when hovering over it.
[image]

The code i am using :

```
 tooltips: {
                enabled : false,
                custom : function(tooltipModel){
                    var tooltipEl = document.getElementById('custom-tooltip')
                   //if tooltip component doesn't exist yet
                    if(!tooltipEl){
                        tooltipEl =  document.createElement('div')
                        tooltipEl.id = 'custom-tooltip'
                        
                        tooltipEl.innerHTML = '<table></table>'

                        document.body.appendChild(tooltipEl)
                    }

                    //making component opacity the same as in model
                    if(tooltipModel.opacity === 0){
                        tooltipEl.style.opacity = 0;
                        return;
                    }

                    tooltipEl.classList.remove('above','below','no-transform',)

                    if(tooltipModel.yAlign){
                        tooltipEl.classList.add(tooltipModel.yAlign)
                    }else{
                        tooltipEl.classList.add('no-tranform')
                    }


                    function getBody(bodyItem){
                        return bodyItem.lines
                    }
                    //adding information inside component
                    if(tooltipModel.body){
                        var titleLines = tooltipModel.title || []
                        var bodyLines = tooltipModel.body.map(getBody)

                        var innerHTML = '<thead>'

                        titleLines.forEach(function(title){
                            innerHTML +=  '<tr><th>' +  title + '</th></tr>'
                        })

                        innerHTML += '</thead><tdboy>'

                        bodyLines.forEach(function(body,i){
                            var colors = tooltipModel.labelColors[i]
                            var style = `
                                background : ${colors.backgroundColor};
                                border-color : ${colors.borderColor};
                                border-width : 2px;
                            `

                            var span = '<span style="'+style+'"></span>'
                            innerHTML += '<tr><td>' + span + body + '</td></tr>'

                        })

                        innerHTML += '</tbody>'

                        innerHTML += '<button>button inside tooltip</button>'

                        var tableRoot = tooltipEl.querySelector('table')
                        tableRoot.innerHTML = innerHTML

                    }

                    var position = this._chart.canvas.getBoundingClientRect()

                    tooltipEl.classList.add('custom-tooltip')

                    tooltipEl.style.opacity = 1
                    tooltipEl.style.left = position.left + window.pageXOffset + tooltipModel.caretX + 'px'
                    tooltipEl.style.top = position.top + window.pageYOffset + tooltipModel.caretY + 'px'
                    // tooltipEl.style.pointerEvents = 'none'



                }
```

I have a working custom tooltip on :
https://jsfiddle.net/wL179b2p/

I only need something that prevents the tooltip from closing when not hovering over it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use like html string use document.createElement.So can add event to the element dynamically

```js
var d1 = document.createElement('div');
 var node = document.createTextNode("paragraph 2");
d1.appendChild(node);
var d3 = document.createElement('div');
var button = document.createElement('button');
button.setAttribute('onclick', 'GetTableValues()');
//here GetTableValues is the javascript funtion called
d3.appendChild(button);
d1.appendChild(d3);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution i found is to create event listeners :

```
        customTooltip.addEventListener('mouseout',()=>{
          customTooltip.style.opacity = 0
        })

        customTooltip.addEventListener('mouseover',()=>{

          customTooltip.style.opacity = tooltipOpacity
        })
```

This helps me keep the tooltip open when i am hovering over it

Answer (score 0):

I use the `events: ['click']` config in options:

```js
window.onload = function(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d')
    var chart = new Chart(ctx,{
        type : 'line',
        data : {
            labels : ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
            datasets : [
                {
                    label : 'My first dataset',
                    data : [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45]
                }
                
            ]
            
        },

        options : {
                events: ['click'],
            tooltips: {
                enabled : false,
```

For details, read further here ...
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/interactions.html#event-option